# Is it a way to split chars with ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm tryna do an ANTLR translator from Markdown format to HTML document and I found this problem when I try to recognize bold format. This is my ANTLR rule:
`TxtNegrita : ('**' | '__') .*? ('**' | '__') {System.out.println('<span class="bold">' + getText() + '</span>');};`
Unfortunately, the `getText()` function retrieves all the recognized String, including `**` at the beginning and at the end of the String. Is it a way to delete that chars using ANTLR (obviously, in Java is perfectly possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve created a Lexer rule which results in a single token.  That is the expected behavior.

That rule looks more like something I’d expect in a parser rule.

(rules begin with upper case characters (conventionally all uppercase to make them stand out), and parser rules begin with lowercase letters and result in parse trees where each node has a context which gives you access to the component parts of your parser rule.

In ANTLR it is quite important to understand the difference between Lexer rules and parser rules.

Put simply... your input stream of characters is converted to an input stream of tokens using Lexer rules, and that stream of tokens is processed by parser rules.

Tokens are pretty much the “atoms” that parser rules deal with and their values are simply the string of characters that matched the Lexer Rule.